# how can I add records to the zone file without restarting the named service?

Tags: centos, dns, bind

I'm working on centos6.5 and bind9 and I have managed to add records to a DNS zone by doing this steps:

creating the key:

```
 dnssec-keygen -a HMAC-MD5 -b 128 -n HOST example.com.
```

editing conf. file:

```
// TSIG Key
key "example.com." {
     algorithm hmac-md5;
     secret "THE KEY GENERATED ABOVE";
};
zone "example.com" IN {
     type master;
     file "example.com.zone";
     allow-update{ key "example.com."; };
};
```

give the named authorization to the /var/named folder:

```
# chown -R named:named /var/named
# find . -type d -exec chmod 770 {} \;
# find . -type f -exec chmod 660 {} \;
```

I have adding records using this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Defining Variables
DNS_SERVER="localhost"
DNS_ZONE="example.com."
USER_NAME="dd2.example.com."
IP="192.168.1.7"
TTL="60"
RECORD=" $USER_NAME $TTL A $IP"
echo "
server $DNS_SERVER
zone $DNS_ZONE
debug
update add $RECORD
show
send" | nsupdate -k Kexample.com.+157+55566.key
```

it didn't return any error.

I test if I add this record by using dig command:

```
#dig +short dd2.example.com.
192.168.1.7
```

but the problem that the record added doesn't appear in the zone file 'example.com.zone'.

even when I use reload: `rndc reload MYZONE` or `rndc reload`
it returns an error message like this:

```
[root@dd Shells]# rndc reload example.com.
rndc: 'reload' failed: dynamic zone
```

but when I restart the named service: `service named restart`
the record appears in the zone file.

my question is :

Is it a way to the record to be added to the zone file without restarting the named service?

Comment: even though `service named reload` worked , is it considered as a good solution for performance? because `service named restart` is absolutely not   @Christopher

Comment: Thanks, but did you have any idea why `rndc reload zone` didn't work?

Comment: `service named reload` didn't work too @Christopher

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer:

my problem was that BIND can't `rndc reload zone` with the dynamic zones so BIND won’t allow us to reload a dynamic zone. So we have to tell bind to temporarily stop allowing dynamic updates. This is handled with the freeze option.

```
rndc freeze example.com
```

then reloading

```
rndc reload example.com
```

then allowing dynamic updates again:

```
rndc thaw example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 rndc reconfig
```

This should do the trick.

But be aware that this command adds (removes) new (old) zones, but it cannot modify existing ones

Comment: I want to add records to the zone,, not adding a new zone @Neven

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. There is no other way than rndc reload. Have you tried with SOA serial number change?

Comment: but why it won't work? @Neven

Comment: Have you changed serial number in SOA?

Comment: no I haven't, but is it necessary every time I modify my zone ,and if I do it what it would do ?

Comment: The best answer is: It depends on your DNS topology, do you have more than one DNS, bla bla bla... But I've found that changing SOA SN is really good thing to do, because I've encountered similar problems in past. So I always increment serial number. This is my proposition to you also and than try to reinitiate zone reload.

Comment: I have learned that if I don't increment SOA SN, BIND won't reload the zone contents. So, SN incrementation is essential.

Comment: @Neven, you should post the serial number increase as an answer. It **needs** to be incremented, that is how it works.

Comment: Changing the serial number is the way to tell "hey! the records have changed" and that info will be widespread to other servers. Without changing it, you could locally force reloading of the file by shutting down and restarting BIND, but the changes won't be seen outside (as other servers/clients will rightfully use their cached date, assuming no changed have happened since the serial number is the same).